# Using Eclipse tutorial, instructions say "unlock the emulator"

Tags: android

Newbie trying to get hello world to work.  Eclipse tutorial says to "unlock the emulator" what does this mean and how do I do it?  Also when I start the emulator my CPU meter pegs at 100% and stays there.  Can't really do much after that.  Is the emulator really that CPU intensive?

Comment: Dude unlock the screen !

Comment: Start your emulator and go make a sandwich, when you come back it should have calmed down a bit.

Answer (score 2):

> Eclipse tutorial says to "unlock the emulator" what does this mean and how do I do it?

The Android emulator behaves like an Android device. The second and subsequent times you start it, it will boot through to a lockscreen, which you swipe to unlock the same way as you do a device.

> Also when I start the emulator my CPU meter pegs at 100% and stays there. Can't really do much after that. Is the emulator really that CPU intensive?

That depends a bit on the development machine. The ARM emulator is CPU-intensive. You are welcome to [switch to the x86 emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm) if your development machine is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Just swipe upwards to unlock the emulator so that it can run apps. This can be done simply like the way you unlock your android smartphone

Answer (score 0):

You can lock your Emulator Device by running this command from command prompt 
adb shell input keyevent 26

You can unlock your Emulator Device by running this command from command prompt 
adb shell input keyevent 82

After running the unlock command, you might have to wait for some minutes.
Above Unlock command will work, when you does not have any security lock